# Format ERD Diagram in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, erd

I have created dynamic ERD diagram using SQLAlchemy library in Python but the problem is that I want to format the rough structure of ERD like ERD entity color, relationship line, etc... Can anybody help me? I'm sending you the full code.

```
from sqlalchemy_schemadisplay import create_schema_graph
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import os

# Create a database engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:ZubairHasan123#@127.0.0.1/sakila')

# Create a metadata object
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

# Create a schema graph
graph = create_schema_graph(
    metadata=metadata,
    show_datatypes=True,  # Show data types on the graph
    show_indexes=True     # Show indexes on the graph
)

print(graph)

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin/'
# graph.write_png('D:\ATS\ERDiagram\ERD\schema_graph.png')
graph.write_svg('D:\ATS\ERDiagram\ERD\schema_graph.svg')
```